# Pywinauto typing in the wrong field

Tags: pywinauto

I'd appreciate any comments on this issue.

I'm using PywinAuto to automate a DeskTop application.
And I'm executing this command to fill out a field in the screen==>

app.SISLOGSistemadeinformaçõeslogísticasRodoviário.Pessoa.Edit.set_edit_text("077775555000100")

But it is filling the wrong field. Below is a print of the application tree.
Looking to the picture and take in account the command that I'm using, is it possible to identify what is wrong..?

Thank in advance for any comments.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `.Edit2.set_edit_text("...")`. Magic attribute lookup is typo resistant (approximate to some degree), also it follows "find first" approach. Another non-obvious thing is that `Edit0` and `Edit1` is matched to the same element, while `Edit2` is the next one, `Edit3` is the third one and so on.

P.S. Maybe it's better to switch `Inspect.exe` to "UI Automation" mode to see more properties.

Comment: Hi Vasily.. Thank you for the replay..

Comment: Hi.. Vasily.. Thank you for your replay.. I have already tryed to change the Edit2...Edit3...Edit20, but the key values always goes to the wrong field. I ahve changed to "UI Automation" but I didn't found any additional properties that help.

Comment: The field that I want has the attribute "Class=MSMARKWndClass", do you if is it possible to indentify it by this class name..?

Comment: You can get the correct `child_window(...)` specification from `app.SISLOGSistemadeinformaçõeslogísticasRodoviário.Pessoa.dump_tree()` output and copy-paste it instead of `.Edit` attribute access. See this part of Getting Started Guide: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#how-to-know-magic-attribute-names

Comment: Also please make sure you're using `Application(backend="uia")` explicitly for creating `app` object. Default backend is "win32" now which is relevant to Spy++ tool (less useful).